# Cannot assign "<QuerySet []>": " must be a "" instance

Tags: python, django

I am trying to save this field from Forms.py, which seems to be causing this error: Cannot assign "<QuerySet [Vehicles: Toyota]>": "Group.vehicles" must be a "Vehicle" instance.

Everything saves correctly through the admin page but not through the form.

```
class GroupForm(forms.ModelForm):
    vehicles = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(), queryset=Vehicles.objects.all())

class Meta:
    model = Group
```

Models.py:

```
class Vehicles(models.Model):
Vehicles = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
MaxRange = models.DecimalField(null=True, max_digits=20, decimal_places=3, default=Decimal('0.000'))
Speed = models.DecimalField(null=True, max_digits=20, decimal_places=3, default=Decimal('0.000'))

def __str__(self):
    return self.Vehicles

class Group(models.Model):
group = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
vehicles = models.ForeignKey(Vehicles, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

def __str__(self):
    return self.group
```

'Group' consists of one type of vehicle.

views.py:

```
def home(request):
group = Group.objects.all()
form = GroupForm()
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = GroupForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        obj = form.save(commit=False)
        obj.vehicles = form.cleaned_data['vehicles']
        obj.save()
    return redirect('/')

context = {'group': group, 'form': form}
return render(request, 'calculator/Input.html', context)
```

Thanks you for any input

Comment: `vehicles` is a `ForeignKey`, so that means it can only contain *one* `Vehicle`. Likely you want to use a `ManyToManyField` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, didn't need a checkbox widget. I deleted the line: "vehicles = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(), queryset=Vehicles.objects.all())" and just left 'vehicle' as a field in Forms.py under class Meta: It saves/ users can only select one option now.